# How to filter the autocomplete value in Drupal8?

Tags: autocomplete, drupal-8

Had 2 taxonomy Variables States and Cities I need to add them to a content type. Among them, one is dropdown(Select List) & Another is Autocomplete list. Here the Autocomplete list depends on the select list.

Let's say we have terms in States as(CA, AZ, OH, ND) & Terms in Cities as( Sunnyvale, Paloalto, Cleaveland, Columbus, Phoenix, Sedona, Bismark, Jamestown)

When a user selects a state from select list i.e, OH and he goes to the second dropdown for autocomplete when he starts typing it should filter only the affiliated cities to OH in the autocomplete list as well

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via using #ajax in form alter. 
Also, You need to make one taxonomy with parent-child relationship rather than two separate one.

Use Contribute module [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs)

OR

Below is the custom sample code :

```
function example_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'example_form':

      $states = [];
      $vid    = 'states';
      $terms  = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, 0, NULL, FALSE);
      foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if ($term->depth == 0)
          $states[$term->tid] = $term->name;
      }

      $form['states'] = [
        '#title'      => t('States'),
        '#type'       => 'select',  
        '#options'    => $states,        
        '#required'   => TRUE,
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback'  => 'getCityList',
          'event'     => 'change',
          'wrapper'   => ['autocomplete_city_container'],
          'method'    => 'replace',
          'effect'    => 'slide',
          'progress'  => [
            'type'    => 'throbber',
            'message' => t('Fetching city...'),
          ],
        ]      
      ];

      $form['city_alter'] = [
        '#type'       => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => ['autocomplete_city_container']],     
      ];
      $form['city_alter']['city'] = array(
          '#title'    => t('City'),
          '#type'     => 'select',   
          '#required' => TRUE,
          '#options'  => [],                
        );
      if (!empty($form_state->getValue('states'))) {
        $cities   = [];
        $stateTid = $form_state->getValue('states');
        $vid      = 'city';
        $terms    = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, $stateTid, NULL, FALSE);
        foreach ($terms as $term) {                
            $cities[$term->tid] = $term->name;
        }

        $form['city_alter']['city'] = array(
          '#title'    => t('Size'),
          '#type'     => 'select', 
          '#required' => TRUE,
          '#options'  => $cities,                
        );
      }
    break;
  }
}
function getCityList(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {  
  return $form['city_alter'];
}
```